# When transforming data, why use resampling to estimate transformed values?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, data-transformation, resampling

I am working through a machine learning book and am using the `caret` package in `R`. There is a function, preProcess, that uses resampling (intended for use on a training set I think) to estimate transformed values (e.g., log-transformation).

My questions are:

1. Why would resampling be necessary? Why would you not just apply the transformation to your entire dataset?
2. Why would you even need to **estimate** the transformed values? In my field, typically you would just apply whatever formula to your variables (e.g., calculate the log), and get newly-calculated variables that have undergone transformation.

My hunch is that this has something to do with computational efficiency, but am curious what the rationale for this procedure is.

Comment: I suspect that the resampling involves methods of estimating statistics (for example such as $p$-values) for the model by drawing information from the observations without making distributional assumptions; [Jackknife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackknife_resampling) and [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) methods are examples of resampling.

Comment: In this case, the resampling and estimation is applied to the raw data. That is, estimation in this case means predicting what e.g., the log-transformed values would be (rather than just applying the log to the values). I don't get why anyone would do that, but. I'm thinking there must be a reason since there's a popular function dedicated to doing it.

Comment: Well, for one thing, the mean of a logarithm of data is not the logarithm of the mean of the data, as an example. Generally mean logarithm < logarithm of mean.